# Resolve NetBIOS name in C# on linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

There is a code in C# using NetAPI32.dll to get MAC Address, computer name and computer domain name. Is there some code with the same functions under linux?

Comment: Doesn't Mono offer the same c# functions under Linux?  What does it matter what is used under the hood?

Comment: And what about NetAPI32.dll? Does Mono support it? I think Wine will needed too.

Comment: Haven't you heard of an _abstraction layer_?

Comment: @MickyD, can you show example? I have been compiled code in C# with xbuild. I have exception, what where is not netapi32.dll. Where is import dll, not C# functions. And how can you take NetBIOS name, MAC address of remote machine. C# offers only System.Environment.MachineName.

Comment: We're not here to write code for you

Comment: You say that **Doesn't Mono offer the same c# functions under Linux? What does it matter what is used under the hood?** How can you do this in Linux `[DllImport("netapi32.dll",EntryPoint="Netbios",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]`. Can you?

Comment: Read the .NET manual

Comment: natapi32.dll is a Windows dynamic link library. Mono migration analizer - [link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/).

Comment: But i dont want to use Wine.  I'm asking about **the way of taking some data via NetBios in Linux of remote computer !!!**

Comment: I like apple strudel.   The sky is blue.   Surfing swans have the best life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have not found any ready solutions, saw only this [code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28122909/) and uderstood that to do.

I wrote a class for constructing and parsing packets. I send a complete package on 137 (UDP) port, and get an answer. This class is not for all cases, but it suitable for me. I receive hostname, domain and MAC address.

Used

- [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)
- nslookup (Windows)
- mnblookup (Linux)
- [SMBLibrary](http://iknowu.duckdns.org/files/public/SMBLibrary/SMBLibrary.htm)